# Pricing plan specification according to DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am trying to enforce limits in web API according to the pricing plan specification.

Example:

User subscribes to one of three plans. Each plan allows number of social media profiles to be connected for a single user. Currently limits are enforced in web api handler when user requests to connect new profile.

As more specifications needs to be met it increases complexity of api handler and it begs for abstraction. I was reading a book about Domain Driven Design and came across SPECIFICATION pattern.

Question is where specification pattern should be applied. In application layer (where api handler is) or in Domain layer?

If it belongs to domain layer should I enforce specification in Repository when adding new profile?

```
    socialMediaProfileRepository.add(socialMediaProfile, specification);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule should most likely be enforced in an aggregate root, such as `UserAccount`. If the `UserAccount` tracks it's linked `MediaProfile` and has a `PricingPlan` that defines the `MediaProfileLinkageSpecification` it could look like:

```
void linkMediaProfile(userAccountId, mediaProfileData) {
    userAccount = userAccountRepository.findById(userAccountId);
    mediaProfile = new MediaProfile(mediaProfileData);

    //throws if the related user profile linkage spec is not satisfied
    userAccount.linkMediaProfile(mediaProfile);
    userAccountRepository.save(userAccount);
}
```

[image]